# Fix Future Unchecked Assignment Warning

Tags: java, concurrency, future, executorservice

I have a code which pings all IP addresses in a given sub network. It is using concurrency to improve performance since waiting for a timeout for every IP address would take much longer otherwise:

```
/**
 * @param subNetwork The subnet to scan
 * @return A list of internet protocol addresses that are reachable
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws ExecutionException
 * @throws InterruptedException
 */
public static List<String> getRespondingInternetProtocolAddresses(final String subNetwork) throws IOException,
        ExecutionException,
        InterruptedException
{
    final List<String> activeInternetProtocolAddresses = new ArrayList<>();
    int startingIndex = 1;
    int upperBound = 256;
    int poolSize = upperBound - 1; // Query concurrently for best time savings
    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);
    List<Future<Runnable>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int currentSubNetIndex = startingIndex; currentSubNetIndex < upperBound;
         currentSubNetIndex++)
    {
        final int subNetIndex = currentSubNetIndex;

        // Query each Internet protocol address concurrently for speed purposes
        Future task = threadPool.submit(new Thread(() ->
        {
            String currentInternetProtocolAddress = subNetwork + "." + subNetIndex;

            try
            {
                if (Ping.isReachable(currentInternetProtocolAddress))
                {
                    activeInternetProtocolAddresses.add(currentInternetProtocolAddress);
                }
            } catch (IOException exception)
            {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }));

        tasks.add(task); // TODO Fix unchecked assignment warning
    }

    for (Future<Runnable> task : tasks)
    {
        task.get();
    }

    threadPool.shutdown();

    return activeInternetProtocolAddresses;
}
```

When adding a new task to the tasks list, I'm getting an unchecked assignment warning:

```
tasks.add(task);
```

I tried to generify [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) by replacing it with `Future<Runnable>` but it created a compile error instead since [`submit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.lang.Runnable)) returns a `Future<?>`.

What can I do to fix the warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this you can declare tasks as `List<Future<?>>` and `task` as `Future<?>`.

Comment: Here, OP definitely don't need `Future` at all

Comment: The question is how to fix the compilation warning. If it's a question of how to implement this, well simply spawning Threads is a bad thing to do when already using a thread pool.

Answer (score 0):

`Future<T>` is used when some result of type `T` should be returned from a task -- then you get this result and use it.

If you need just to wait until all tasks execute, use `threadPool.submit(Runnable r)`. Then after `threadPool.shutdown()` invoke [`threadPool.awaitTermination()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) -- to block until all tasks complete.